# What is the general pattern for archive tables which need to preserve original child relationships

Tags: sql, t-sql, ef-code-first

Say I have a table with many 1-to-many child relationships (e.g. contact numbers), and I have an equivalent archivetable which matches the columns of the normal table.

I'm facing the problem of archiving a row by moving the data from the normal table to the archivetable. The problem exists where the child table relationships break. How do I preserve the child data whilst being able to archive? At the moment I can only see one way which is to have nullable FK relationships from the child tables to the archive table, and then re-wire the keys on archiving.

Is this the best solution?

Comment: Are we talking about 2 tables being archived into 2 archive tables?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do a logical archive, and use a `BIT` field that indicates a field isn't active?

Comment: Can you provide an example schema?  One extension from JNK's suggestion is a time-varying database - Every record is marked as being effective from one timestamp to another.  This can, however, caus ecomplexity to grow pretty quickly.

Comment: Imagine a Customer, CustomerPhones and CustomerEmails tables.  When a customer is deleted it is archived by moving the row into ArchiveCustomer. However all relationships are setup for 1-to-many between the Customer and CustomerPhones tables.

Comment: JNK - I thought about this but then I wanted to have a separate archive table. Its caused more problems due to the parent/child relationships though.

Comment: If you have an `ArchiveCustomer` table, why can't you have an `ArchivePhone` table?  That said, I'd probably use @StevieG's answer, or something similar (probably only a single `from` timestamp, to avoid gaps and such).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in our temporal database environment:

Ensure that your archive tables contain copies of the current latest records plus all of the previous versions.

You will also need `valid_from` and `valid_to` columns on each table to record the times at which each version of the records were valid. You can populate these using triggers when you write to the archive table..

`Valid_to` on the latest version of a record can be set to the maximum date available. When a newer version of a record is inserted, you'd update the `valid_to` of the previous version to be just before the `valid_from` of the new record (its not the same to avoid dupes)..

Then, when you want to see how your data looked at a given time, you query each table using SQL like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table a
JOIN table b ON .....
WHERE <time you're interested in> BETWEEN a.valid_from AND a.valid_to
AND <time you're interested in> BETWEEN b.valid_from AND b.valid_to
```

Comment: Time is not the problem here, they are archived on demand not based on the age of the record.

Comment: +1 - this is indeed the most common pattern I'm aware of. It doesn't break the relational model, grows/evolves with the schema, and allows you to write your queries just once, rather than needing 1 query for current records and one for archive records.

Comment: @StevieG - I'm not archiving the data in a historical way, I'm performing 'closing' actions and 'soft deletes'. I don't need to store multiple sets of data in the same table over time. At a basic level the Archive flag would suffice, but I like the idea of having a separate table.

Comment: @jaffa - Ok, I get it.. Your only option in this case is to archive your child records when you do the delete. You can do this by setting the FK relationships to CASCADE. You can still use the model I've outlined, though - the triggers will ensure that the archive is kept up-to-date..

Comment: @StevieG - can you tell me how to go about doing this, I want to preserve all the child data even when archived.